# New SharePoint Install best practices

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, installation

I have scoured the internet but can't find a precise answer to what I'm looking for and wondered if anyone could help. I have been testing SharePoint 2010 on a stand alone server. Never used it before. The boss wanted an intranet, shared document area and knowledge base, plus other functionality in the future. Its gone well using the trial period so we are going ahead with it.

I have read about how to set up the production server using a virtual environment and least privilege accounts etc, so I'm fine with that. I need help with how to set up another test server for future testing and then migrate any changes over with no downtime if possible as we will be sharing documents with clients over the internet.

I work in IT but am in no way a SharePoint developer, I am new to this and have a basic knowledge of wsp deployment as I've done this on the test server we have, but need to keep this fairly simple.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few posts that can be helpful regarding SharePoint installations -

- Todd Klindt's recent post on [SharePoint 2010 Install Guidance](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=320) has been a most useful checklist.
- Todd has another good post -  [Top 10 SharePoint 2010 Configuration Mistakes -- and How to Fix Them](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-misconfigurations-141636).

Also, Fabian Williams' two-part post is very illustrative in showing the [Installation Procedure for Base SharePoint 2010 Install](http://fabiangwilliams.wordpress.com/2009/11/07/installation-procedure-for-base-sharepoint-2010-install-part-1-of-2/).

Regarding the development and deployment of app solutions across the stages (dev, testing & production), you may find this overview useful - [Application Lifecycle Management in Microsoft SharePoint 2010.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2010/11/17/application-lifecycle-management-in-microsoft-sharepoint-2010.aspx)